# how do I edit my wordpress site navigation

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I saw [cargo collectives](http://cargocollective.com/featured) website site navigation has a cool little circle indicator next to each link. I want to be able to add something similar to my website but I dont know which file I want to be changing.

I'm currently using a wordpress theme called Square and I've currently got the effect I want working on one link which is the home url link by adding a class called 'indicator' by editing the functions.php file within the theme however it doesnt appear to show on any of the other resulting in the menu looking like this http://d.pr/i/Cv1U

```
/**********************************************
MAIN MENU FALLBACK
***********************************************/

function menu_fallback() {
    if(is_front_page()){ $class="current_page_item"; }
    ?>
    <div id="dropdown" class="menu clear">
        <ul id="menu-main-nav" class="sf-menu">
            <li class="<?php echo $class; ?>">
                <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><?php if(get_option('square_home_menu')!="") { echo get_option('square_home_menu'); } else { _e( 'Home', 'square_lang' ); } ?> <div class="indicator"></div></a>
            </li>
            <?php wp_list_pages( 'title_li=&sort_column=menu_order' ); ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

I was just wondering if there was something I could add to this PHP string to make it add the indicator class to all other links added into the menu or is there another file in the WP structure I should be editting to get this to work?

Please bare in mind I am a PHP noob

Comment: Have you tried to do with CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the dots have no semantic value I would go for a CSS solution.
I would use `a:after{content: '&bull;'}`
Here's a quick example http://jsfiddle.net/5Ahy3/

Alternatively you could use background images.